# Preloading Webpages using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I would like to get a `div` to pre-load on to a page before it redirects so that it doesn't flicker while loading.

What I am trying to accomplish is the header (an `img`) and navigation (a `ul`) all under the `<header>` tag to appear not to reload and to stay in place while the content under it fades out with `page1.html` and fades in with `page2.html`.

I am hoping there is a way to load the header on to the page so that it doesn't flicker when changing between them.

Comment: If the header contains the same things then why reload it? Why not load the "different" parts such as the main content of the page?

Comment: As Mihai said, you could simply use an AJAX GET request to get the contents of page1.html and page2.html to dump it into your DIV. Then you don't even have to redirect the current page.

Comment: Ok, will have to look in to that as have not used AJAX GET before, would this effect Google rankings as there are less pages if its just loading in to the index page?